# persist data across postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A user clicks `<input type="submit" />` and it runs a query using a value stored in `<input type="text" />`.  Lets say the user looks up item number:

1234

On postback I lose this value.  I decided to put it in a label so the user can see it and I can grab it again on the next postback (a different form).

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Method","Controller"))
            {                
                <label runat="server" style="font-size:2em;">Item: @ViewBag.labels[0].ItemNumber</label><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Create Labels" runat="server" />
            }
```

But, the label isn't posted back in the FormCollection.  How can I achieve this functionality?  I want to store the value "1234" so I can send it again on the second postback with Form2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ItemNumber" value="@ViewBag.labels[0].ItemNumber" />
```

Comment: +1 You showed up first with this answer and it works.  I'll mark it after the timer.

Answer (score 1):

A label won't get posted as part of the FormCollection.

You need to put it into a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.labels[0].ItemNumber" />
```